# Routing an OR path with React-Router

Tags: react-router

I'm routing pages that maintain the same component structure, but their content changes slightly based on the URL. When setting up my routes for this area I'm currently using the following structure:

```
<Route path="/:focusPath/read/agree" component={ViewerLayout} />
<Route path="/:focusPath/read/neutral" component={ViewerLayout} />
<Route path="/:focusPath/read/disagree" component={ViewerLayout} />
<Route path="/:focusPath/speak/agree" component={ViewerLayout} />
<Route path="/:focusPath/speak/neutral" component={ViewerLayout} />
<Route path="/:focusPath/speak/disagree" component={ViewerLayout} />
```

However, this seems repetitive and overly complex. Though it works as is, is there a way I could reshape it to accomplish something like this?

```
<Route path={"/:focusPath"+("/read"||"/speak")+("/agree"||"/neutral"||"/disagree")} component={ViewerLayout} />
```

I realize that the syntax is all wrong, but maybe something that simplifies the 6 lines it took to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't recommended, but it should work for your use case. You can pass a Regex to `path`. Here's a snippet that will get you the right idea.

```
<Route path="/:focusPath/read/(/agree|neutral|disagree/)" component={ViewerLayout} />
```

I'm rubbish at Regex so that probably won't work as is, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, I didn't realize that I could use a Regex!

If you want some practice in it, or just to play around trying to make something work, [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) is a great tool to get better at regular expressions. ;)